# How to set custom dimension values using AngularFireAnalytics?

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, firebase-analytics

I'm using @angular/fire (version 5.3.0) and its `AngularFireAnalytics` module for Firebase Analytics. It works great! Except I cannot find a way to set values for custom dimensions, which we need in our solution.

We also need to set these values dynamically, rather than once during initialization, as the values change during usage of the app.

Does anyone know if there is a hook I can implement that will let me set custom dimension values before the page_view event is sent by `AngularFireAnalytics`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this.

Import the following:

```js
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAnalytics } from '@angular/fire/analytics';
```

Inject both `NgZone` and `AngularFireAnalytics` into your component:

```js
constructor(
    private zone: NgZone,
    private analytics: AngularFireAnalytics
) { }
```

and then, in an `async` method, call:

```js
await this.zone.runOutsideAngular(async () => {
   await this.analytics.setUserProperties({
        my_custom_prop: custom_prop_value,
        another_prop: other_prop_value
    });
});
```

This will set the properties for all subsequent events.

Comment: wait what is this doing outside of angular's zone? Also have you noticed any delays with the values being set in firebase?